# Adding TextViews at the end of an AsyncTask

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, android-activity

I need to add text to a ScrollableLayout after it's remotely retrieved from an `AsyncTask`. Since I don't know the number of strings involved, I need to programmatically create as many `TextView`s as needed.

Layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_phone_mainView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_phone_linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_phone_lblTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/view_phone_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_phone_lblWarning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/view_phone_warning"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Activity

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.view_phone_wait));

        pDialog.show();

        task = new MessageLoaderTask(); //Returns String[] on callback
        task.execute((Void) null);
    }

    public void onRulesLoaded(String[] messages) { //Directly called by OnPostExecute
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_phone_linearLayout);
        if (messages != null) {

            for (String m : messages) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(m);
                tv.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceSmall);
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                container.addView(tv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
        }

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

**I am sure**, by debug, that strings are correctly valued. The result is that the title label gets displayed, the warning is hidden but below there is only white......

I tried to scroll and noticed that the scrolling area is veeeeeeeeeery long, compatible with the long `Lorem ipsum` stub text I used for testing. If I truncate via debug one of the strings to empty (there are only 2) the scrollable area is shorter in height. I use the light theme, so I expect black text on white background.

```
tv.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceSmall);
tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

were added at a second time when everything was failing. No difference whether they are in place or not. What can I do to fix?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand you have an array of strings? so for each of those array of strings you create a  textview synchronously, and 1 string in order in every textview?

Comment: For each string in the array I need a TextView. OK I could merge all strings into one with \n\n and use a single TextView only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your ScrollView would be increasing in length if this were the sole problem, but it seems like you need to set your LinearLayout's orientation to vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

add all the Strings to this `EditText` by keeping '\n' between the strings. So that every thing will be aligned properly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't need a textbox, and also I couldn't be able to display other controls unless the layout was set to vertical as described in @kabuko's answer